# How can I have both a legend and data labels, with different labels, in Highcharts?

Tags: charts, highcharts

I need to create a pie chart with labels indicating what each area means, but also another info overimposed over each area. If I use both data labels and a legend, they'll show the same text. How can I have both with different texts, or emulate that effect?

A mock of what I'd like to get:

[image: A mock of what I'd like to get]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [format](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.format) or [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter) config properties of the dataLabels, you can make them say whatever you want.

```
           pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function(){
                        return 'Y Value: ' + this.y;  // y value
                    }
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
```

Quick [example](http://jsfiddle.net/b1xbproe/).